# How can i exclude deleted records from embedded document mongo db spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to get only those Messages that are not marked as deleted in a embedded document.For example 
for my collection as fellow

```
{
   "users":[
            {
           "email":"user@company.com"            
            "messages":[
                        {
                          "text":"some message",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "text":"some message",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "text":"some message",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "text":"some message",
                          "isDeleted":"true"  
                        },{
                          "text":"some message",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        }

            ]            

            }
    ]  

}
```

So the result should be as 4 messages not 5.

I am trying this

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("messages.isDeleted").is(false));
User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query,User.class);
```

But this will not work as my query is returning user and when i get users messages its contains all the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwind the messages array using `$unwind` operator and then apply the criteria using `$match` operator

```
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$messages");
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("messages.isDeleted", false));

AggregationOutput output = mongoTemplate.getCollection("user").aggregate(unwind, match);
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
Iterator<DBObject> iterator = output.results().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    DBObject obj = (DBObject) iterator.next();
    Message message = emrDataStore.getConverter().read(Message.class, (DBObject)obj.get("messages"));
    messages.add(message);
}
```

The `List<Message> messages` will hold the result - messages which are not deleted